# Showing and hiding multiple divs occupying the same space with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby

I understand there is alot of these exact type questions on here that i have checked through but i still cant get mine to work.

When i click the anchor it doesnt even make it to console.log?

```js
$('.panel').hide();
$('.show').click(function(event){
 console.log('test')
 event.preventDefault();
 $('.panel').hide();
 $('#section' + $(this).attr('id')).show();
});
```

```css
.panel{
 display: none;
 position:absolute;
 border: solid teal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li> <a href="#" class="show" id="1">Customers order</a> </li>
  <ul>
 <li> <%= link_to "Purchased" %> </li>
 <li> <%= link_to "Cancelled" %> </li>
  </ul>
<li> <a href="#" class="show" id="2">Your Products</a></li>
  <ul>
 <li> <a href="#" class="show" id="3"> "Add products" </a> </li>
  </ul>
<li> <a href="#" class="show" id="4">My Messages </a> </li>
<ul>

<div class="col-md-7">
 <div id="section1" class="panel" >
   <%= form_for @new_product, :url => vendors_path do |form| %>
   <%= render partial: '/vendors/form', object: form %>
   <%= form.submit "Submit" %>
   <%  end%>
 </div>

 <div id="section2" class="panel">
    panel2
 </div>

 <div id="section3" class="panel">
    panel3
 </div>

 <div id="section4" class="panel">
   panel4
 </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: make sure you wrap your code inside `$(function() { //your code here });` or that you are not seeing any errors in the console

Comment: Converted your code to snippet and is working fine. The problem is that you need to wrap your JS inside `$(function() {  });` as mentioned by Toni Michel Caubet above.

Comment: On my browser (Chrome), when I click on the anchors, it logs `test` to the console.

Comment: Also, you have already hidden your `.panel`s with the line of css `display: none`, so you don't have to hide it again with `jQuery#hide()`

Comment: Ok thanks thats solved it!

Answer (score 3):

I think you are missing ";" after console.log()
It can block all after that.